# How can increase Azure App Service 230 sec request time out

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have hosted an Asp.NET MVC application on Azure App Service. I am getting a timeout exception which elapsed more than 230 seconds. How can increase it on Azure App Service?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, 230 seconds is the maximum amount of time that a request can take without sending any data back to the response.

We couldn't increase it in azure web app.

Here are two work around.

One is you could move your application to a cloud service or created a VM where you have control over those settings.

Another way, you could also use async pattern in MVC.

For example:

Firstly, you could send the request to the MVC to tell the server start to work and returns an http 202.

Then you could send request every seconds or minutes from client to check the server work. If it works completely return 200 to tell the client has already completely.

Comment: Can you really " tell the server start to work and returns an http 202" ? I believe the await keyword returns the control back to the caller but does not return anything. Is there an example of this you could provide pls? Thanks.