# Using Async/Await with Azure App Services Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have a .Net Web Api hosted as Azure App Service. (I have to call this from ADF as a web activity.)

This API has some code which runs for a long time so [I want to make this Async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820256/how-can-increase-azure-app-service-230-sec-request-time-out).

This is how I am testing:

```
[Route("apiA/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AsynccallController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<String> PostA()
        {
            var strTask = await Longfunction();
            return strTask;
        }

        private Task<string> Longfunction()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300));
            return Task.FromResult("value1");
        }

    }
```

And testing from postman: 
[image]

According [to this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#basic-overview-of-the-asynchronous-model), the await keyword should return the control to the caller function (in this case postman) before it executes the sleep. But I do not see that happening. It still waits for those 300 seconds to send response to postman, which is like a sync call. why?

And secondly if it does send control back at 'await', then when and how does the return statement send the value back?

Thanks.

Comment: The `await` does return control (and a `Task<>` object) to the caller, but the caller (the .NET Web API runtime) won't send the HTTP response back to the client until that task has completed.

Comment: Thanks @noseratio Is there a way to send that response back even before the task completes? I need a way to fire and forget that api call. I don't even need to get any response back.

Comment: Traditionally you would use something like `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`, but I don't think that works when hosting with Azure. Perhaps, `IApplicationLifetime` could help. Not an Azure expert, but I think you should use dedicated services like Azure Queues or Azure Functions to run your fire-and-forget tasks, which you'd initiate from your Web API and then return without awaiting the results.

Comment: It is not usually a good idea to let a task persist beyond the end of the HTTP transaction. When the transaction ends, the pipeline is torn down, and much of your context will be either missing, disposed, or in an invalid state.

Answer (score 1):

1. You almost never want to use `Thread.Sleep()` - `Task.Delay()` uses a `Timer` under the hood and is async (enabling the thread to perform other work) while `Thread.Sleep` blocks!
2. You can - hypothetically - "fire and forget" by omitting the `await` before the `Longfunction()` call or by using `Task.Run(() => Longfunction())` - please be aware that this is not a smart thing to do, e.g. your task isn't protected against app pool recycling.
3. If you want to offload long-running operations the right way, I very much suggest you look into  [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io).

Comment: Using `Task.Run` like that in a Web API is a bad idea, same as simply invoking `Longfunction` a in a fire-and-forget manner task, without observing the `Task` it returns. Think about what may happen if your Web API process is torn down and recycled. See my comments to the OP's question.

Comment: @noseratio - hence the reference to Hangfire ;)

Comment: Using `Task.Run()` in this manner is literally never a good answer.

Comment: Is this still a problem if I am just running a batch job? If it  gets killed I should be able to kick off a rerun manually.

Answer (score 1):

> This API has some code which runs for a long time so I want to make this Async.

That answer is recommending an "async pattern". Specifically, [this asynchronous messaging pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn589781(v=pandp.10)). This pattern has nothing to do with the `async` and `await` keywords. The asynchronous messaging pattern is using the term "asynchronous" with a very broad definition; the `async` keyword is one very specific implementation of asynchrony that does not apply here.

To actually fix your issue, you should have your action method generate a request ID, add a "request" message to a reliable queue (such as an Azure Queue), and return the request ID to the client. Next, you'll need an independent background worker; since your web app is an Azure App Service, you may find [Azure Web Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) a good choice for background workers, though you should consider Azure Functions as well. Finally, you'll need a way for the worker to communicate with your frontend to let it know when the work is done; there's a wide variety of possible approaches here, from SignalR to some kind of shared "work database" that the frontend can poll through your App Service API.

> And secondly if it does send control back at 'await', then when and how does the return statement send the value back?

You are correct; the HTTP response *cannot* be sent back at the `await`, or else there would be no way to send the actual result value as the response.

> According to this documentation, the await keyword should return the control to the caller function (in this case postman)

This is where the misunderstanding is. Postman did not call your function; ASP.NET did. `await` is correctly yielding to ASP.NET, which returns that request thread to the thread pool. ASP.NET does *not* complete the request until the action method completes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just need to run some code that generates some files every day. Web jobs seems like I have to manage the underlying architecture and more complicated, while Azure functions is appealing (being serverless etc.) I read it has time out issues. Also the generation of the files can be a trigger for my subsequent steps to kick off, so I dont need to pool or communicate back to the caller.

Comment: @Gadam: Ah, if you need to run it off a *timer* and not an *HTTP event*, that's simpler. And I would recommend Azure Functions in that case; it has built-in support for timer triggers. AF on a consumption plan has a max timeout of 10 minutes (feature, not bug); [if you want infinite timeouts, use the App Service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout).